# Setting Socket Receive Buffer Size, gets truncated to 244KB

Tags: linux, sockets, buffer

I'm trying to increase the size of my socket receive buffer size using setsockopt() on linux.  I can set it successfully to any value below 244KB.  Any value above 244KB gets truncated to 244KB.

There appears to be some sort of system limit in place, but I can't figure where it is coming from, as it doesn't correspond with values below:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem 
4096    87380   4194304
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem 
4096    16384   4194304
$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default 
124928
$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default 
124928
```

The default value is 87380 as expected, but I can't increase it to 4194304.  It gets limited to 244KB.  Interestingly that value is 2X rmem_default, do I need to change that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From man page for TCP:

> ```
>    The maximum sizes for socket buffers declared  via  the    SO_SNDBUF  and
>    SO_RCVBUF  mechanisms  are  limited by the global net.core.rmem_max and
>    net.core.wmem_max sysctls.  Note that TCP actually allocates twice  the
>    size  of  the buffer requested in the setsockopt(2) call, and so a suc-
>    ceeding getsockopt(2) call will not return the same size of  buffer  as
>    requested  in  the  setsockopt(2)  call
> ```

So what you pass for `SO_SNDBUF/SO_RCVBUF` gets doubled while allocation. And as such you cannot pass the max value (4194304) in `setsockopt`

Comment: Thanks I was able to change it by changing net.core.rmem_max